# Fetch not null values in one column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Below is my query

SELECT * FROM companystatus  where company_name='Fifth Borrower' ;

I want the not null values in single row for one borrower.[image: current output]

Expected output

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation usually helps in such requirements, e.g.

```
select 
  company_code,
  company_name,
  max(c2015),
  max(c2016),
  max(c2017)
from companystatus
where company_name = 'Fifth Borrower'
group by company_code,
         company_name
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to select my columns as column name present in the table are integer?

Comment: In Oracle, a column name can't begin with a digit unless you enclose its name into double quotes. In my opinion, that's a bad idea. That's why I *presumed* that real column names aren't 2015, 2016, etc.